# How to hide the zero values in BarChar in MPChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a lot of values with after big gaps, example one value is 1000 the other will be 7500 and so on, When i plot these values on BarChart, the chart is also displaying columns for 1001, 1002, 1003..., i want to hide these columns.

Answer (score 1):

As such functionality is not suppotred, I suggest you follow a different way.

Instead of passing a lot of 0's to the plot, pass only the values that have a value of more than 1.

So instead of this:

```
+------+-----+
| 1000 | 100 |
+------+-----+
| 1001 | 0   |
+------+-----+
| 1002 | 0   |
+------+-----+
| 1003 | 0   |
+------+-----+
| 7500 | 100 |
+------+-----+
| 0    | 0   |
+------+-----+
```

Parse your data and remove 0's. So that your data looks like:

```
+------+-----+
| 1000 | 100 |
+------+-----+
| 7500 | 100 |
+------+-----+
```